# window.history.back voltando apenas uma página

Tags: javascript, ionic

Estou com problema com `window.history.back()`, pois ele está retornando apenas uma página.

Utilizo a seguinte função:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Register the event listener
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
        }

        // Handle the back button
        //
        function onBackKeyDown() {
            if($('.upage:visible').attr("id") == 'listar_CELULAS'){
                var r=confirm("Você realmente deseja sair do aplicativo ?");
                if(r==true){
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }else{

                }
            }else{
                console.log("ta entrando aqui");
                window.history.back();
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Preciso que retorno todos até o ponto inicial da pilha. Para colocar na pilha do `history` utilizo está função:

```
function activate_page(sel, have_state)
{
    var $dn = $(sel);
    var is_vis = $dn.is(":visible");
    if(!is_vis)
    {
        $dn.parents("body").find(".upage").addClass("hidden");
        $dn.removeClass("hidden");
    window.history.pushState({upage:sel}, sel, document.location.origin + document.location.pathname +sel);
    $(document).trigger("pagechange");
    }
}
```

Provavelmente o ionic seja parte neste problema, na verdade não to entendendo direito o momento que cada um está fazendo algo, segue meu código do ionic:

```
angular.module('ionic')
  .run(function($ionicPlatform,$ionicPopup, $state,$ionicHistory){
    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
      //console.log(window.history);
      if($state.current.name=="app.listar_CELULAS"){
        alert("entro aqui");
        navigator.app.exitApp();
      }
      else {
        //window.history.back();
      }
    }, 100);
});
```

Aqui é a função que teoricamente povoa o historico de paginas visitadas:

```
function activate_page(sel, have_state)
{
    var $dn = $(sel);
    var is_vis = $dn.is(":visible");
    if(!is_vis)
    {
        $dn.parents("body").find(".upage").addClass("hidden");
        $dn.removeClass("hidden");
        window.history.pushState({upage:sel}, sel, document.location.origin + document.location.pathname +sel);
        console.log(window.history);
        $(document).trigger("pagechange");
    }

}
```

Onde está o erro ?

Obrigado por enquanto.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O `windows.history.back()` retorna apenas uma página, se quiser retornar mais páginas deve usar `windows.history.go(-2)` por exemplo.

- Isto `history.go(-1)` equivale a isto `history.back()`
- Isto irá retornar duas páginas: `history.go(-2)`

Negativo `history.go(-x)` retrocede e positivo `history.go(x)` avança a quantidade especificada (trocando o x por um numero inteiro).

### Usando eventos do Cordova

O próprio botão `document.addEventListener("backbutton" ...)` já é um evento de voltar, não precisa usar `window.history.back` novamente, a página já esta voltando, faça assim apenas:

```
    function onBackKeyDown() {
        if($('.upage:visible').attr("id") == 'listar_CELULAS'){
            var r=confirm("Você realmente deseja sair do aplicativo ?");
            if(r == true){
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }else{

            }
        }else{
            console.log("Voltou uma página");
        }
    }
```

### Voltando até o começo

Existe também a propriedade `history.length`, com ela você pode saber quantas páginas já avançou no total e fazer aplicar no parâmetro do `history.go(x)`, aparentemente o numero de páginas passadas no nele tem que quer um numero exato menos a página atual, ou seja se você navegou 20 vezes e usar `history.go(-50)` não vai acontecer nada. Então tente assim:

```
window.history.go(-(window.history.length - 1));
```

Documentação:

- Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History
- InternetExplorer/Edge: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536443(VS.85).aspx

Exemplo de uso:

- Primeiro clique no botão <kbd>Páginar</kbd> quantas vezes quiser e observe os botões de navegação do browser (aqui no site mesmo).
- Depois clique no botão <kbd>Voltar ao começo</kbd> e observe novamente os botões de navegação do browser.

```js
function inicio() {
    window.history.go(-(window.history.length - 1));
}

function paginar() {
    var current = parseInt(String(window.location.hash).replace(/^#/, ""));

    if (isNaN(current)) {
        window.location.hash = "1";
    } else {
        window.location.hash = ++current;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="paginar();">Páginar</button>
<button onclick="inicio();">Voltar ao começo</button>
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33383/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-renan-rodrigues).

Comment: Não quero que ele volte ao inicio quero que ele desfaça a fila, por exemplo fui paginas (1,2,3,4,5) cliquei em voltar ele voltar na 4, ai da 4 fui pra 6 depois 7 ficando assim (1,2,3,4,6,7) clico em voltar ele volta na 6. É disto que preciso. @Guilherme

Comment: @RenanRodrigues quando eu formulei a resposta a sua pergunta era confusa, eu só não tive tempo realmente de testar o Cordova. Acho que já tínhamos chegado a um consenso no chat não?

Comment: Não havia funcionado, porque ele voltava apenas um, eu descobrir que o window ele grava apenas a ultima pagina visitada, ou seja não tinha como voltar mais. Porém meu problema não foi resolvido.

Comment: Quanto a `window` gravar apenas uma ou mais eu não sei, acho que funcione, o problema me parece o ambiente do teu aplicativo. Como eu disse, ainda não tive tempo de instalar Phonegap e o Cordova que é o seu caso. Talvez você não tenha habilitado o histórico. Todavia eu combinei que assim que possível iria instalar e tentar resolver e editar a resposta ;)

Comment: Ok, aguardo seu contato, irei adicionar a parte do código que povoa o windows.history

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.