# window.history.pushState

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou utilizando a função `pushState` para povoar o `history`, até ai tudo certo, porém ele na hora de utilizar o `windows.history.back()` consegue apenas voltar uma vez. A função que adiciona é o seguinte:

```
function activate_page(sel, have_state)
{
    var $dn = $(sel);
    var is_vis = $dn.is(":visible");
    if(!is_vis)
    {
        $dn.parents("body").find(".upage").addClass("hidden");
        $dn.removeClass("hidden");
        window.history.pushState({upage:sel}, sel, document.location.origin + document.location.pathname +sel);
        $(document).trigger("pagechange");
    }

}
```

E para voltar utilizo :

```
angular.module('ionic')
  .run(function($ionicPlatform,$ionicPopup, $state,$ionicHistory){
    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
      //console.log(window.history);
      if($state.current.name=="app.listar_CELULAS"){
        alert("entro aqui");
        navigator.app.exitApp();
      }
      else {
        window.history.back();
      }
    }, 100);
});
```

Preciso que ele volte todos até o inicio da pilha, do jeito que está fazendo ele volta apenas uma pagina.

Obrigado desde ja.

Comment: Aqui tem uma pergunta semelhante com uma resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105371/window-history-back-voltando-apenas-uma-p%C3%A1gina

Answer (score 0):

A função do **window.history.back()** é justamente voltar apenas 1 página, para voltar mais deverá usar o **window.history.go(-**"*nº de páginas retornadas*"**)**

Da uma olhada nessa resposta, a situação é parecida com a sua ["window.history.back voltando apenas uma página"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105371/window-history-back-voltando-apenas-uma-p%C3%A1gina)