# Redirecionar página pra anterior PHP (history.back)

Tags: php

estou passando por um probleminha, quando compro um item na loja ele redireciona para página da loja principal, mas a loja é por categoria, eu queria colocar pra quando comprar permanecer na mesma página ou da um history.back com um delay não sei se é possível. Por favor se alguém puder ajudar.

```
$redirectLoc = $insertItem? '/loja.php':'index.php';
```

Esse é o Redirec pra onde vai, já tentei por das seguintes formas.

```
$redirectLoc = $insertItem? '/#':'index.php';
$redirectLoc = $insertItem? 'javascript:history.back()':'index.php';
$redirectLoc = $insertItem? '/loja.php?categoria=?':'index.php';
```

Mas não consigo de nenhuma maneira, alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

```
if($redirectLoc) {
    // Redirect to the specific page
    header("Location: $redirectLoc");
    exit();
}
```

?>

Esse é um outro código semelhante que tem no .php não sei se isso pode ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javascript:history.back()` não funcionará no header, isso é instrução do cabeçalho http de resposta e não do corpo da página. Pra fazer funcionar terá que ser algo como:

```
if($redirectLoc) {
    echo '<script>history.back();</script>';
    exit;
}
```

Se quiser voltar mais de uma:

```
if($redirectLoc) {
    echo '<script>history.go(-2);</script>';
    exit;
}
```

HTTP funciona assim, é baixado o conteudo e então o navegador vai renderizar e executar os scripts javascript, isso depois de baixado, diretamente no teu navegador, ou seja, não tem relação alguma com o que esta no PHP, já foi baixado, o navegador nem sabe que aquilo foi gerado via PHP no server-side (lado servidor)

o `echo ...;` vai gerar um texto que vai ser baixado pelo navegador na máquina do usuário, então só será executado depois que o download for concluido, o exit apenas interrompe qualquer processo no server-side após o echo ali usado, mas não tem nada haver com o front-end também.

Sobre redirecionamento no javascript leia mais em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105373/3635